# short form of closure in swift, lazy loading

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, closures, lazy-loading

Im reading `Strong reference cycle for closure` from Apple docs. Below is a declaration of a lazy var using closure:

```
lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }
```

Below is a syntax of closure in Swift

```
{(parameters) -> return type in
   statements
}
```

They dont look the same but I know that the first `asHTML` is a short form of closure

Can someone walk me through how I derive a short form form original syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration reads

```
() -> String
```

Which means that the closure takes no arguments, and produces a String when called. This closure strongly captures the variable self to be able to use text.

If we take the closure definition

```
{(parameters) -> return type in
     statements
}
```

The above asHTML can be rewritten as

```
{ () -> String in
    statements
}
```

Or

```
{ (Void) -> String in
    statements
}
```

Which is the same as

```
lazy var asHTML = asHTML()

func asHTML() -> String {
    ....
}
```

As an additional note, you can also rewrite the lazy asHTML declaration as

```
lazy var asHTML: String = {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }()
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift allows you to omit parts of the closure syntax depending on the context to make it easier for reading.

Into your case you assign an autoclosure to the asHTML variable.

From Apple's documentation about autoclosures

> An autoclosure is a closure that is automatically created to wrap an
>   expression that’s being passed as an argument to a function. It
>   doesn’t take any arguments, and when it’s called, it returns the value
>   of the expression that’s wrapped inside of it. **This syntactic
>   convenience lets you omit braces around a function’s parameter by
>   writing a normal expression instead of an explicit closure**.

You can read more about autoclosures and closures syntax [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).